# how to use pointer to pointer to access pointer element in struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    int *member;
} mystruct;

void main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    mystruct **data;
    data = (mystruct**)malloc(sizeof(mystruct*));
    int c = 5;
    printf("%x", data);
    (*data)->member = &c;
    printf("Member: %d", *((*data)->member));
}
```

Error: Segmentation fault

I expected it would print "5" in the source code

Comment: Okay, you allocate a pointer to a mystruct. Which mystruct does that pointer point to?

Comment: Sidenote: [don't cast malloc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `(*data)` good, dereferencing the pointer returned by `malloc`. `->member` ***bad***, dereferencing uninitialized memory (inside the chunk returned by malloc), not a valid pointer.

Comment: Take a pencil and a piece of paper and draw the pointer with arrows where they point to, and it should become pretty clear why your program doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Segmentation fault
>
> I expected it would print "5" in the source code

It is because you have only allocated a pointer to your struct and this pointer is not referencing a valid memory location. It invokes Undefined Behaviour (UB). You need to allocate the space for the structure itself.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    mystruct **data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    *data = malloc(sizeof(**data));
    int c = 5;
    printf("%p %p", (void *)data, (void *)*data);
    (*data)->member = &c;
    printf("Member: %d", *((*data)->member));  //or*data[0]->member))
}
```

- `void main(....` is invalid
- do not cast the result of malloc. If it does not compile - you use C++ compiler to compile C code which is wrong
- use objects instead of types in `sizeof`
- you have to use `%p` format to print pointers. Pointers have to be converted to `void *`

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
data = (mystruct**)malloc(sizeof(mystruct*));
```

you allocated memory for one pointer of the type `mystruct *`. That is uninitialized.

Thus dereferencing this uninitialized pointer obtained by the expression `*data`

```
(*data)->member = &c
```

invokes undefined behavior.

At least you should write

```
data = (mystruct**)malloc(sizeof(mystruct*));
*data = malloc( sizeof( mystruct ) );
```

That is you need to allocate memory for an object of the type `mystruct` the data member `member` of which will be assigned.

Also pay attention to that using the conversion specifier `%x` to output a pointer

```
printf("%x", data);
```

also invokes undefined behavior. Instead you need to write

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )data);
```

Or you could include header `<inttypes.h>` and write

```
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf("%" PRIxPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )data);
```

Comment: thanks that is really helpful. Still, I want to ask why we have to cast (void *)

Comment: @hoang15nguyen It is a requirement for the conversion specifier  p. From the C Standard "p The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
manner."